# not getting " auth_token" in url query when loging to facebook?

Tags: android

I am using FBConnect  in my game to post score on facebook wall. Now login interface has changed, whenever I click on login button the connectToSession method is not executing because it didn't get `" auth_token "` from  url query. Just two days before it was executing properly and  delegate method sessionDidLogin also getting executed. Before in sessionDidLogin method I was switching to FeedActivity class for publishing game score to facebook wall.